# Can Spectron tests run in their own desktop?

Tags: mocha.js, electron, spectron

We have mocha+Spectron testing an Electron app. They run for about a minute currently. The app window keeps opening and closing, which is annoying in a couple of ways:

1. If the user clicks, or types when it has focus, in the app window during a test, it can often fail the test.
2. Each new window opens up with focus, which makes it hard to use any other program.

(That is the behaviour on Linux, xfce desktop; I can imagine other OS/window managers might have slightly different behaviour?)

Is there a way to run Spectron tests in their own desktop? Maybe in another X session, that just runs for the life of the tests? (Though, ideally, looking for a solution that would work on Mac, and Windows, too.)

(I saw references to mocha-headless, but I think that is for testing websites? Could it be used with Spectron and Electron apps?)

Comment: In a now-deleted answer, this link was mentioned as useful:  https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/4834.   This one on headless spectron might also help: https://github.com/electron/spectron/issues/323